# Android Drawable XHDPI only - avoid lint warning

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-lint

In my project I have drawables that are used only in case of tablets. So if I put the images on the XHDPI, lint complains that the image should be in the other dimensions too. Is ignoring lint the best approach in this situation?

Comment: I think not. This can cause unexpected errors. Can't you put some images with the same names inside other folders too. Perhaps use blank (transparent images) just to work around this compatibility issue.

Comment: Ideally you should put image files in other folders. Just resize them, but be careful if images a .9.png. Resizing will not work properly then.

Answer (score 0):

You can place image in `drawable-nodpi` or in `drawable` folder. They are not exist by default you need to create folders in your resources

Comment: if you put images under "drawable" lint complains too

Comment: drawable = drawable-mdpi